# Java - opening program, website or folder from one same methode/class

Tags: java, windows, url, process

right now, i have nearly experience for one year with JAVA, but encountered a (large) problem!

I'm busy with a program that is a sort of alternative start-menu of Windows.
It wil look like this:

> **Tab 1**
>
> *JButton*: Google.com
>   *JButton*: GMail.com
>   *JButton*: Google Agenda
>   etc...
>
> **Tab 2**
>
> *JButton*: Word
>   *JButton*: OneNote
>
> **Tab 3**
>
> *JButton*: World of Tanks
>   *JButton*: BeGone
>
> **Tab 4**
>   *JButton*: Xampp
>   *JButton*: Documents

---

As you can see, i have filled all tabs with all buttons.
These buttons are from the class ShortCut and that class extends JButton (of course :) ). The ShortCut-class has an String witch is the URL, like http://www.google.com/.

**My problem**

I want, if the button is clicked, the saved url witch in it, will be opened. But i have 2/3 different url's:

1. Website links (like "http://www.google.nl/")
2. Program links (like "c:\myProgram.jar")
3. Folder links (like "c:\Users")

--> What i really, really want is to get a function or class, that could open all those 3 kinds of links! Does somebody have such an function?

--> If that's not possible, could somebody give me advise how to realise the opening of those 3 kinds of url's?

You can really help me, because i stuck with this!

thanks in advance,

Dave

ps: sorry for my bad english! :)

Comment: Could you just use `System.exec("start " + uri)` ?  This will delegate dealing with different types of URI to the underlying windows OS.  Note, of course, that this will only work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Desktop here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html